# Why different init files for login and non-login interactive shells?

Tags: bash

I understand the difference between login and non-login interactive shells, but I never really understood why exactly the former source `~/.bash_profile`<sup>1</sup> while the latter source `~/.bashrc`.

Mind you, as far as I can remember, every example of `~/.bash_profile` I've seen at some point sources `~/.bashrc`.  Therefore, in practice, the question reduces to: why is `~/.bash_profile` sourced only for login shells?

I realize that some environment variables need to be set only once, and it may be a bit of a pain to write some of these settings in a way that can tolerate repeated sourcings.  For example, suppose a `~/.bash_profile` sets `PATH` like this:

```
PATH=/my/custom/path:$PATH
```

If such `~/.bash_profile` were sourced more than once, it would result in repeated instances of `/my/custom/path` at the beginning of `PATH`.  It is not terribly difficult to write the setting of `PATH` in such a way that avoids such repetitions, but it's hard to beat the simplicity and convenience of the setting shown above.

Is avoiding the added complexity required to deal with such repeated settings the main reason for having `~/.bash_profile` be sourced only by login shells?

Alternatively, is less a more substantial reason for not having a common initialization file for both login and non-login interactive shells?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Most of my mentions of `~/.bash_profile` should really be replaced by "`~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`".  I hope that the simplification of omitting `~/.profile` does not inflict too much violence on the truth.</sup>

Comment: Setting environment variables isn't the only thing that's done or that can be done in these files. You can display unread mail counts, for example. And I'm sure there probably any number of other things which need to be done only once for a session. Why *shouldn't* there be separate files for things that need doing repeatedly vs things that need to be done only once?

Comment: Having output being generated when logging in non-interactively (e.g. when using `rsync` other the network) will corrupt the communication (e.g. causing `rsync` to give an error).

Comment: It's because history, nothing more. FWIW, notice that it's a complete mess when a "login shell" should be started, with some people insisting that each pseudo-terminal should have a login shell running in it (it's the default in tmux to start login shells, and on some systems xterms are configured to run login shells too). Also, starting a login shell does not mean  having or not having an entry in the login databases (utmp, wtmp), or having a human user actually authenticated in.

Comment: And btw, for people who may not understand it as you do, the difference between a login and a non login shell is whether its `$0` / `argv[0]` starts with a dash or not. That's all.

Comment: This site has many excellent questions about this or that piece of obscure UNIX history that on the surface seem unanswerable but eventually turn out to have surprising, informative, enlightening answers.  The fact that this question is asking about design rationale and/or historical reasons **does not** make it opinion-based.